# If $AB = I$ then $BA = I$: is my proof right?

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to prove that for matrices $A,B \in M_n (\mathbb K)$ where $\mathbb K \in \{\mathbb R, \mathbb C, \mathbb H\}$ if $AB = I$ then $BA = I$.

My proof is really short so I'm not sure it's right:

If $AB = I$ then $(BA)B = B$ and therefore $BA=I$?

Comment: So you are saying that if you have two matrices $C$ and $D$ where $CD = D$, then $C$ always is $I$?

Comment: Here you can find proof : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3852/if-ab-i-then-ba-i

Comment: It’s not correct – see Thomas’ comment. And @agha: I think she or he is more interested in finding an own proof.

Comment: You must use arbitrary matrix not a specific one

Comment: For clarity, you should add the step $(BA)B=B(AB)$, and you just proved that $(BA)B=B$. If $B$ is not invertible, you cannot conclude $BA=I$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The implication $(BA)B=B \Rightarrow BA=I$ is a little quick and not always true...

But observe that
$$1=\det(BA)= \det(B)\det(A)$$
thus $B$ is invertible and it follows that 
$$BA= BA(BB^{-1}) = B(AB)B^{-1}=BB^{-1}=I.$$

Answer (score 5):

Consider
$$
C = \pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0}, D =\pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0}
$$
Here $CD = D$, but $C$ is not the identity. That is, your proof is not clear.

It has already been given in the comments above, but you can find a proof here: [If $AB = I$ then $BA = I$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3852/if-ab-i-then-ba-i)

Answer (score 4):

Your proof isn't correct: If in a ring with unit we have $ab=b\iff(a-1)b=0$ then we have not necessarily $a=1$ or $b=0$ unless we work on an integral domain *(and of course $\mathcal M_n(\Bbb K)$ isn't an integral domain)*.

To prove this result notice that *(by a classic result)*  that $AB=I$ imply that $A$ is surjective and $B$ is injective *(since $I$ is bijective)* and we conclude that $A$ and $B$ are invertible using the rank-nullity theorem.